# MySQL Creating a Music Database

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm working the creation of a music database.

I think I need 3 tables, `playlist`, `music` and a table to link them together.

```
Playlist table:
play_id PK,
Created_By,
play_name

music table:
music_id PK,
track_title,
artist,
album
```

I want a user to create as many playlists as they want. They can add as many tracks to the playlist as desired. I understand the playlist part of the table but when it gets to adding tracks to the playlist table from the music table is where it gets fuzzy. If i have the music table filled with tracks how can i have lets say 2 tracks show up on the one playlists?

I'm a little unsure of how to do this and if my table structure is good or do i need to add more fields. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with primary keys and foreign keys I'm assuming i would need a separate table to link them. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

> If i have the music table filled with tracks how can i have lets say
> 2 tracks show up on the one playlists?

You should have something like:

**`Tracks`**:

- `TrackId`,
- `Title`,
- ...

**`PlaylistsTracks`**:

- `Id`,
- `PlayListId`,
- `TrackId`,
- ...

For the two other tables that you already has:

> Playlist table: play_id PK, Created_By, play_name
>
> music table: music_id PK, track_title, artist, album

There is a problem with these tables. Your tables this way aren't [***normalized***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). You should create two extra tables:

**`Users`**:

- `Id`,
- `Name`,
- ..

**`Artists`**:

- `ID`,
- `Name`,
- ...

Then:

- Make the `Created_By` a foreign key that references the `users(Id)` column.
- Create a foreign key `ArtistID` in the `music` table instead of the `artist` column, references `Artists(ID)`.
- Make `track_id` column instead of the `track_title` column in the `music` table.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track, I think.  A table setup like the following should do what you need, I think (this is off the top of my head, so excuse any syntax issues):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tPlaylist;
CREATE TABLE tPlaylist (
    playlistId INT,
    /* ... Other Data ... */
    PRIMARY KEY (playlistId)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tMusic;
CREATE TABLE tMusic (
    musicId INT,
    /* ... Other Data ... */
    PRIMARY KEY (musicId)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS tPlaylistMusicMap;
CREATE TABLE tPlaylistMusicMap (
    mapId       INT,
    playlistId  INT,
    musicId     INT,
    trackNumber INT,
    PRIMARY KEY (mapId),
    /* ... Other Data ... */
    FOREIGN KEY (playlistId) REFERENCES tPlaylist (playlistId),
    FOREIGN KEY (musicId) REFERENCES tMusic (musicId),
    UNIQUE KEY (playlistId, musicId, trackNumber)
);
```

The basic gist of this is that you let user's create their playlists in the tPlaylist table (single row per user playlist), you put all your music track data in tMusic, and the mapping table tPlaylistMusicMap is where the individual tracks in each playlist get stored.  A unique key on playlistId, musicId, and trackNumber allow the same tMusic entry to be in a playlist multiple times at different spots in the track list.

Edited to add foreign key constraints.